# How to change a git repository cloned with --bare to match one cloned with --mirror?

Tags: git, version-control, git-push

This issue is not the same as [git - how to mirror file from other repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427413/git-how-to-mirror-file-from-other-repo) or [How do I update my bare repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382679/git-how-do-i-update-my-bare-repo)

Since a repository cloned with `--mirror` is a bare repository, can I make a repository cloned with `--bare` be like one cloned with `--mirror`?  Can it be done by simply modifying the config file?

If not, is there other method which can convert a bare repository to a mirror repository?

Another question, **Why can I not use git push --all in a mirror repo**, while this command can be ran in a bare repo?

Comment: You can trivially edit the config file in any editor. Just make the branch references the way they are in a mirror repo (+refs/*:refs/*), remove the remote tracking branches (from packed-refs and refs/remote/*/*), add `mirror=true`, and re-run a `git fetch`.

Comment: @fork0 this trivial operation seems not works...

Comment: exactly what does not work? Error messages? (BTW, I didn't mention in what section is `mirror=true` to be added. It is `[core]`).

Answer (score 17):

To change a repository cloned with `git clone --bare` into one that matches what it would be with a `git clone --mirror`, do the following:

```
$ git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/*:refs/*" 
$ git config remote.origin.mirror true
```

Then do a `git fetch` and everything should be up-to-date.

Comment: Further cleanup to get rid of remote tracking branches (all branches are local on a mirror): `git branch -r | xargs -rt -I{} git branch -d -r {}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have clone your repo with [`git clone --mirror`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), then a [`git push --all`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push), following the [default `matching` push policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586687/what-is-the-result-of-git-push-origin/9749477#9749477), will push all local branches to the remote repo.

But if your remote repo has been added to your local repo as a remote reference (ie your local repo has been cloned from *another* remote repo), then a `git push --all secondRemoteRepo` won't find many matching branch to push to, unless you fetch those branches first.
So this should work:

```
git fetch secondRemoteRepo
git push --all secondRemoteRepo
```

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays:

```
git remote add --mirror=fetch origin <url>
```

Then

```
git fetch
```