# How to make a git clone --bare into a git clone --mirror

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I accidentally created a copy of a repo with `git clone --bare` and now I can't update from the original repo. [This GitHub article](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/) advises `--mirror` for updates:

> If you want to mirror a repository in another location, including
>   getting updates from the original, you can clone a mirror
>
> git clone --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/repository-to-mirror.git

How can I modify a `--bare` clone into a `--mirror` repo?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959924/whats-the-difference-between-git-clone-mirror-and-git-clone-bare this might help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21688931/5781248 gives the two commands needed

Comment: @J.J.Hakala: `git fetch` fails with `fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository`